# Can't get single category - NodeJs API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I working on my API for the E-commerce app in MERN. I have done a few things already, and now I am trying to get single category. There is no error on console, and I read the code a few times, but postman keeps throwing Cannot GET error. I would appreciate it if someone can tell me what's the deal with this.
The part for creating new category works just fine, also as similar code for getting one product  Code:
Category.js Router

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const { create, categoryById, get } = require("../controllers/category");
const { requireSignin, isAuth, isAdmin } = require("../controllers/auth");
const { userById } = require("../controllers/user");

router.get("/category/:categoryId", get);
router.post("/category/create/:userId", requireSignin, isAuth, isAdmin, create);

router.param("categoryId", categoryById);
router.param("userId", userById);
```

Category.js Controller

```
const Category = require("../models/category");
const { errorHandler } = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler");

exports.categoryById = (req, res, next, id) => {
  Category.findById(id).exec((err, category) => {
    if(err || !category) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'Category does not exist'
      });
    }
    req.category = category;
    next();
  });
}

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const category = new Category(req.body);
  category.save((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: errorHandler(err)
      });
    }
    res.json({ data });
  });
};

exports.get = (req, res) => {
  return res.json(req.category);
}
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong but did you double check the URL in postman?

Comment: Yes, a few times. Trying to get from http://localhost:8000/api/category/5dbf08947ec7502e78e8a425

Comment: I just created a sample app for this problem, and I can get the single category

Comment: @SuleymanSah so, could it be postman bug or something like that?

Comment: Is this router wrapped within an `/api` base route? You'r trying to visit `/api/category/...` so make sure the `/api` is there..

Comment: Use the url from the create url, remove create/:userId and append categoryId value